# How can I cache all view user requests so If the same request is made again it is fetched from cache

Tags: caching, request, xpages, xpages-ssjs, session-scope

I have rather big application with lots of documents and lots of different view controls.

To speed up things and avoid unnecessary view and view search requests I would like to cache the already requested documents or view entries so if users do the same request again the repeats first looks in the cache.

I am thinking about writing a generic function that stores all requested unids in a sessionScope that I can apply to all view collection as my application retrieves values from documents and not view column values.

I guess this kind function need to keep track of which request was made and switch back to non cache content if more rows are needed by the user.

Comment: Is it really necesaary to cache view results? What do you do when a document has been added to the view just between 2 searches/lookups? I would try to understand why the lookups use up the time and fix these problems first.

Comment: Please have a look at my XSnippet. Some details for performance problems are described there: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=workaround-for-perfomance-problems-with-data-containers

Comment: @SvenHasselbach what does this mean "Works currently only with serializable data"

Comment: This means that you cannot use a instance of a NotesObjects directly. If you want to cache a DocumentCollection, you must store f.e. the noteid's in a Vector or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to develop a Bean (Java Class) and bind your controls to the Bean instead of directly to View and Document datasources. Inside the bean you can maintain a cache of the views/documents already loaded.

Comment: I'd recommend using Google Guava caches, because you'll want to control the size to avoid in increasing exponentially. It might also be worth considering an external caching server like ehcache or memcache. Reader rights may need to be considered though. And bear in mind that, unless you reproduce what the XPages runtime does, you may have a performance hit.